# Generate javascript bundles in ASP.NET MVC 5 without npm

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `ASP.NET MVC 5` project created in `Visual Studio 2017` which uses `Vue.js` and `ES6`.

Is there a way to transpile and minify javascript files without using `npm` and maybe using some `Visual Studio` extensions and/or some `nuget package(s)`?

All solutions that I found use `gulp` with `brawserify` or `webpack` and I don't want to use any of those tools.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The below only works for minification of bundles. I missed the requirement of transpiling the *.vue files.

In BundleConfig.cs add `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` `bool BundleTable.EnableOptimizations {get; set;}`"Gets or sets whether bundling and minification of bundle reference is enabled."

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{ 
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundlesjquery").Include(
       "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
       "~/Scripts.jquery.validate*"));

    System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I use `.vue templates` and `es6 modules`, files which need to be first transpiled and then minified